# An optimality condition for constrained problems using subgradients

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function which is *not* differentiable everywhere and let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set. Consider the problem of minimizing $f(x)$ subject to $x \in K$. Is it true that $x^\star$ is the optimal solution in $K$ if and only if $$g^T(y-x^\star)\geq 0, \forall y \in K, \forall g \in \partial f(x^\star),$$
where $\partial f(x^\star)=\{g \in \mathbb{R}^n|~~f(y)\geq f(x^\star)+g^T(y-x^\star)~~\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$ is the set of subgradients of $f$ at $x^\star$?

I can only prove one direction. Since $g^T(y-x^\star)\geq 0, \forall y \in K, \forall g \in \partial f(x^\star)$, by definition of $\partial f(x^\star)$ we have that $f(x^\star)\leq f(y)$ for every $y \in K$, thus $x^\star$ is optimal. What about the other direction, that is proving that $x^\star$ is optimal implies  $g^T(y-x^\star)\geq 0, \forall y \in K, \forall g \in \partial f(x^\star)$? Is it even true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Let $n=1, f(x) = |x|$, and $K=[0,1]$. Then $x^*=0$ minimizes $f$ over $K$, but $g = -1 \in \partial f(0)$ and $g(1-0) <0$.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. Is the other direction I was proving correct instead?

Comment: Yes, the proof you gave for the other direction is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Are you by any chance aware of any necessary and sufficient  conditions to link subgradients with variational inequalities? I'm trying to mimic the condition  for optimality $\nabla f(x^\star)(y-x^\star)\geq 0,~\forall y \in K$ for non-differentiable convex functions.

Comment: I think $x^*$ minimizes $f$ over $K$ iff there exists $g\in \partial f(x^*)$ such that $g^T(y-x^*) \geq 0$ for all $y \in K$. But I need to think about it to see if that is really correct.

Comment: Interesting. I had also thought about existence instead of "for all". In case you find a proof, you can post it here under this new related question I asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802528/a-necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-optimality-of-non-smooth-convex-functio . I'll also think about your suggestion in the mean time