# A necessary and sufficient condition for optimality of non-smooth convex functions over convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function and $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set. Consider the problem of minimizing $f(x)$ over $x \in K$. It is well known that, if $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then $x^\star$ solves the problem if and only if $\nabla f(x^\star)(y-x^\star)\geq 0,~\forall y \in K$.

Now suppose that $f$ is not differentiable and let $$\partial f(x)=\{g \in \mathbb{R}^n|~~f(y)\geq f(x)+g^T(y-x)~~\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$$ denote the subdifferential of $f$ at $x$. Are there any necessary and sufficient conditions for optimality that mimic $\nabla f(x^\star)(y-x^\star)\geq 0,~\forall y \in K$, but using subdifferentials for non differentiable functions?

Comment: Your optimality condition is missing a "$\geq 0$".

Comment: Fixed, thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think about this is that $x^*$ minimizes $h(x) = f(x) + I_K(x)$ iff $0 \in \partial h(x^*) = \partial f(x^*) + \partial I_K(x^*)$ iff there exists $g\in \partial f(x^*)$ such that $-g$ is in the normal cone to $K$ at $x^*$ iff there exists $g \in \partial f(x^*)$ such that $g^T(y-x^*) \geq 0$ for all $y \in K$.

(Note that this argument uses the subdifferential sum rule, and the fact that the subdifferential of the convex indicator function $I_K$ at $x^*$ is the normal cone to $K$ at $x^*$.)

Comment: The sum rule only holds because $f$ has full domain.

Comment: @max_zorn Good point. By the way, do you have any favorite convex analysis books other than Convex Analysis by Rockafellar?

Comment: @both In this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10898-004-2696-5 it is argued in the first page that the solution space of the constrained optimization problem I'm considering coincides with the solution spaces of both "VI" and "MVI". "VI" is the problem of finding $x$ such that a subdifferential exists for which $g^T(y-x)\geq 0 \forall x \in K$. "MVI" is the problem of finding $x$ such that for all subdifferentials we have $g^T(y-x)\geq 0 \forall x \in K$. However, there is no reference or explanation for the claim. Any insight?

Comment: Also, it is stated here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-007-0147-z that "VI" as in my previous comment is equivalent to the optimization problem. Though, it is not proved in the paper and I can only show that if $x^\star \in sol(VI)$, then $x^\star$ is optimal, but not the other way around.